# Set paper size of Zebra TLP 2844 programmatically

Tags: windows-xp, printer, powershell, internet-explorer-7, vbscript

I have a lot of Zebra TLP 2844 printers used by domain users. Unluckily by default the paper size is 2" x 4" while I need to have 4" x 3".

The first time each user logs on I have to change manually these settings. Is it possible to apply this size programmatically for each user?

Moreover, in order to have the desired output, I would need to remove the header and footer from Internet Explorer and set each of the four margins to 10mm for each user as well. Any kind of solution would be acceptable (VBS, PowerShell etc).

Searching on Google I've found that within the Windows registry under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Page Setup
```

it's possible to remove the header and footer and to set all 4 margins to 0.3937 inches in order to have 10mm. I've written this reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup]
"footer"=""
"header"=""
"margin_bottom"="0.3937"
"margin_left"="0.3937"
"margin_right"="0.3937"
"margin_top"="0.3937"
```

It works but I don't know how to run it every time a user logs on to the domain. I also still have to set the paper size manually.

Any ideas how to have the above registry settings imported each time a user logs on to the domain, and how to set the paper size as well?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252388) is an article that discribes how to do it. Not sure that it does exactly what you want to do, as it only works for new users, but let me know.